# $|\hat f(y)|<\hat f(0)$ for positive $f\in \mathcal L^1$

Tags: lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $f\in \mathcal L^1(\mathbb R^\nu)$, $f>0$. I want to show that
$$|\hat f(\xi)|<\hat f(0) \qquad \forall \xi \neq 0$$
It is easy to prove that
$$|\hat f(\xi)|\le\hat f(0) $$
In fact
$$|\hat f(\xi)|=\left |\int_\mathbb R e^{-i\langle x,\xi\rangle }f(x)\mathrm dx \right |\le \int_ \mathbb R |e^{-i\langle x,\xi\rangle}||f(x)|\mathrm dx=\int_\mathbb R f(x)\mathrm d x=\hat f(0)$$
but I am having a hard time proving that such maximum cannot be achieved by a non-zero $\xi$.

I tried to suppose by contradiction that there exists $\bar\xi\neq 0$ such that
$$|\hat f(\bar \xi)|=\hat f(0)$$
but I was not able to show a contradiction. There probably is a one liner answer lying somewhere.

**Question**: how can we prove that such $\bar \xi$ cannot exist?

Comment: Take a look at your inequality and consider the cases, when it actually is an equality. For this $arg( e^{-i\langle x,\xi\rangle} f(x))$ must be constant. Does this help?