# Question about $\hat f$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I want to get some clarification for the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340453/hat-fy-hat-f0-for-positive-f-in-mathcal-l1). There is only one comment on a direction to solve this problem. As mentioned by the OP it is quite simple to show that in general $|\hat{f}(y)| \leq \hat f(0)$ when $f$ is nonnegative. But how can we ensure we get the strict inequality whenever $y \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll work on $\mathbb R$ for simplicity. Given $y\in \mathbb R, y\ne 0,$ there exists $z\in \mathbb R$ such that

$$|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-iyx}\, dx| = e^{iz}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-iyx}\, dx$$ $$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{i(z-yx)}\, dx = \text{Re }\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{i(z-yx)}\, dx$$ $$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\cos(z-yx)\, dx<\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, dx=\hat f(0).$$

The reason for $<$ in the last line is that $\cos(z-yx)<1$ except for countably many $x.$

Comment: Nice! To get the result do we solve for what $x$ would make the equality hold and yield the contradiction from there?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I've added to my answer to make it clearer.